# Discord bot TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I am making a bot with a dashboard and I need to take user guilds but when I use user.guilds.forEach it doesn't work. I used to do it too and it worked fine.

```
<% user.guilds.forEach(guild => { %>
 <div class="button">Manage <%- guild.name%></div>
<% }) %>
```

Please help :(

d.js v12

Comment: Which version of discord js you are using?

Comment: since v12 discord introduces the concept of managers so you will need `user.guilds.cache....`